# Foreach Loops Output Incorrectly

Tags: c#

So I have these nested for each loops, and the second one takes the "visits" that are counted within the first loop. However when it outputs the information, it does the first visit, and then changes pages and continues through the loop printing out all occurences of the visits from the first loop. How can I have it print all visits on sheet 1 and then move to the nested loop and print out those results?

```
int r = 1;
int j = 1;
int cell = 0;
//loop that places Visit on Sheet 1 of Excel
for (int i = 1; i < visits.Count(); i++)
  {
   Visit visit = visits[i];
   decimal? charges = visit.TotalCharges();
   decimal? payments = visit.TotalPayments();
   decimal? totAdj = visit.PaymentAdjustments.Where(x => x.nrv_cd.Trim() == "C01").Sum(s => s.pmt_pst_at);
   decimal? actbalance = charges - (payments + totAdj);
   CareGiver attending = visit.AttendingPhysicianCareGiver();

   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, visit.Person.DisplayName());
   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, visit.vst_ext_id.Trim());
   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, visit.LosFormatted());
   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, visit.CodeDetail.cod_dtl_ds);
   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, visit.CodeDetail.cod_dtl_ext_id.Trim());
   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, charges);
   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, payments);
   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, totAdj);
   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, actbalance);
   r++;
   workbook.ChangeWorksheet(2);

      //when moving to this nested loop, it picks up all charge codes for that visit
      foreach (Charge c in visit.Charges)
       {
        workbook.AddCell(j, 0, visit.vst_ext_id.Trim());
        workbook.AddCell(j, 1, c.ChargeDefinition.chg_cod_ext_id.Trim());
        j++;
       }
      //when moving to this nested loop, it picks up all adjustment codes for that visit
      foreach (PaymentAdjustment pa in visit.PaymentAdjustments)
       {
        workbook.AddCell(j, 0, visit.vst_ext_id.Trim());
        workbook.AddCell(j, 1, pa.ChargeDefinition.chg_cod_ext_id.Trim());
        j++;
       }

        workbook.ChangeWorksheet(1);
```

Comment: when do you want the nested foreach loops to iterate? is this only after you have gone for the first loop? Or is it for each time the first loop reads a row?

Comment: @Hituptony - I would like to print it in this order: Sheet 1 - Visit 1, Visit 2, Visit 3 ...Sheet 2 (where the nested loops come in) Visit 1: Code 1, Visit 1: Code 2, Visit 2: Code 1, Visit 2: Code 2, Visit 2: Code 3...and so on for each visit. There are multiple codes being printed for each visit on the second sheet.

Comment: can you comment your code in the above ^^?

Comment: move workbook.ChangeWorksheet(1) outside the for loop. you're printing the values for the first visit, then changing the worksheet. You need to change the worksheet after iterating thru all the visits

Comment: Only if he wants the remaining visits to be on page 2 also.  What this code does is print a visit, change pages, print details, then change pages back, then it loops.  What I want to know is why it doesn't work, it looks like it does exactly what he says it should....although we don't see the end of the loop there either...I'm assuming its located immediately after the `changeworksheet(1)` call.

Comment: Right now it is printing 1 visit, then changing sheets, and then printing off each visit within the first loop on the second page and the individual codes. But then closes. And yes the end of the loop is right after I change back to sheet 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is add more "ChangeWorksheet" commands.  The other is to repeat the entire visits loop again.

Method 1 is exactly what you have implemented, which I have to assume is for some reason NOT what you wanted.  I do however wonder why that is....you get the same result.

It specifically involves printing a single visit, then changing pages and printing the details for that visit, then changing pages back and moving to the second iteration of the outer loop.

Method 2 would look something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < visits.Count(); i++)
{

   Visit visit = visits[i];
   decimal? charges = visit.TotalCharges();
   decimal? payments = visit.TotalPayments();
   decimal? totAdj = visit.PaymentAdjustments.Where(x => x.nrv_cd.Trim() == "C01").Sum(s => s.pmt_pst_at);
   decimal? actbalance = charges - (payments + totAdj);
   CareGiver attending = visit.AttendingPhysicianCareGiver();

   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, visit.Person.DisplayName());
   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, visit.vst_ext_id.Trim());
   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, visit.LosFormatted());
   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, visit.CodeDetail.cod_dtl_ds); 
   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, visit.CodeDetail.cod_dtl_ext_id.Trim());
   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, charges);
   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, payments);
   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, totAdj);
   workbook.AddCell(r, cell++, actbalance);
   r++;
}

//new code
workbook.ChangeWorksheet(2);
for (int i = 1; i < visits.Count(); i++)
{
    Visit visit = visits[i];
    //when moving to this nested loop, it picks up all charge codes for that visit
    foreach (Charge c in visit.Charges)
    {
      workbook.AddCell(j, 0, visit.vst_ext_id.Trim());
      workbook.AddCell(j, 1, c.ChargeDefinition.chg_cod_ext_id.Trim());
      j++;
    }
    //when moving to this nested loop, it picks up all adjustment codes for that visit
    foreach (PaymentAdjustment pa in visit.PaymentAdjustments)
    {
      workbook.AddCell(j, 0, visit.vst_ext_id.Trim());
      workbook.AddCell(j, 1, pa.ChargeDefinition.chg_cod_ext_id.Trim());
      j++;
    }
}
```

Specifically, print all the visits, change pages, go through another loop that prints all the details.  Only change pages once, but you have to go through the visit loop twice.

One thing to remember about writing code, it always executes in order, unless you tell it not to.  This includes loops and other things.  It will always execute in the order its written.  If you want the details to print after *all* the visits, you have to tell it to print all the visits before you tell it to print *any* of the details.

Comment: That makes sense, I think having the nested loop makes it more complicated than it needs to be. Thank you.